# Browser based GUI tool for MongoDB on AWS-Linux-server

Tags: linux, mongodb, database-browser

I want to know if there is any browser based GUI tools available for MongoDB to use on AWS-Linux-Server. I just want to view the collections of Mongo.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, after few hours of suffering i found answer for my own question

To Create Mongo user

---

```
db.createUser({ user: "root" , pwd: "<password>", roles: ["userAdminAnyDatabase", "dbAdminAnyDatabase", "readWriteAnyDatabase"]})
```

## Adminer for MogoDb

Adminer configuration

---

nano adminer.php

search --> connect("mongodb://$N",$sf);

edit if condition --> if($F!="") -->  if($F!="password")

## RockMongo for MogoDb

Installation

---

1. wget https://github.com/iwind/rockmongo/archive/master.zip
2. unzip master.zip
3. config rockMongo to nginx
4. service nginx restart

RockMongo based on php5 so, it's not working on php7

---

so, i used mongo-php-adapter

1. composer require alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter
2. insert the following in index.php

   ---

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

3. edit the following in config.php

   ---

To enable password login
$MONGO["servers"][$i]["mongo_auth"] = true;//enable mongo authentication?